# Saving Joda Date on Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, jodatime, android-jodatime

What is proper way to store Joda Date and Time in android. When I tried to save it on Firebase and got Fatal Exception.
Here is the Snippet of Class of the object I want to save which says:
     "Serializing Arrays is not supported, please use Lists instead"

```
 private String mPlotId;
 private String mAreaId;
 private String mUserId;
 private int mAreaNum;
 private LocalDate mStartDate;
 private LocalDateTime mStartTime;
 private int mHour;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can store your Joda date&times as `long` values by using `toDateTime().getMillis()`:

```
long startDateTimeInMillis = mStartDateTime.toDateTime().getMillis();
```

See "Basic Write Operations" section in Firebase docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write

It shows what kind of stuff and how you can write to db.

Comment: The method you have mentioned prompts error stating has protected access -Ugurcan Yildirim

Comment: Updated my answer. Try this

Comment: That's a good solution, but there's a corner case: `toDateTime` uses the JVM's default timezone to create the `DateTime`, but in case of a [Daylight Saving Time gap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38340388/7605325), this can [throw an exception](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDateTime.html#toDateTime--). Maybe it's better to explicity use UTC, which has no DST effects: `.toDateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC)`